# PySpark: Is there a way to do a .fit() and .transform() in one operation?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to work out how to optimize my .fit() and .transform() in PySpark

I have:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[topic_vectorizer_A, cat_vectorizer_A,
                            topic_vectorizer_B, cat_vectorizer_B,
                            fil_top_a_vect, fil_top_b_vect,
                            fil_cat_a_vect, fil_cat_b_vect,
                            fil_ent_a_vect, fil_ent_b_vect,                            
                            assembler])

# Note that all the operations in the pipeline are transforms only.
model = pipeline.fit(cleaned)

# wait 12 hours
vectorized_df = model.transform(cleaned)

# wait another XX hours
# save to parquet.
```

I've seen things like:

```
vectorized_df = model.fit(cleaned).transform(cleaned)
```

But I'm unsure if that is the same, or somehow optimizes the operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to do. If

- stage is an `Estimator` (like `CountVectorizer`) it is trained in `Pipeline.fit`.
- stage is a `Transformer` (like `HashingTF`) it is returned directly.

Comment: Vectorizers and assemblers are Transformers, right? So why does .transform() not return immediately?

Comment: What is the class of vectorizers?

Comment: CountVectorizer and VectorAssembler

Comment: CountVectorizer is an estimator. It has to be fitted.

Comment: I guess because it has to fit the vocabulary, right? Ok.